# Scenario based check on undefined value in fields in array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have a scenario to check the undefined and empty string in object array in javscript.
Below code is partially working, got stuck.

In the array object,

if field value is undefined or empty return true only when newemp is false

If field value except country other fields are undefined or empty return true only when newemp is true

Else return false when newemp is true and only country is undefined  and if newemp is false and no field is empty or undefined

```
function checkObjects(ob){
 var result = ob.some(e=>e.country === true && (Object.keys(e)===undefined))
 return result
}

var resultfor1 = checkObjects(obj1);
var resultfor2 = checkObjects(obj2);
var obj1=[
 {id:1, newemp: true, country: undefined, cardno: 'S05', name: 'sam'},
 {id:2, newemp: false, country: 'IN', cardno: 'S06', name: 'tomy'} 
]

var obj2=[
 {id:3, newemp: true, country: undefined, cardno: 'S05', name: 'ramson'},
 {id:4, newemp: false, country: undefined, cardno: 'S06', name: ' '} 
]


Expected output 

// obj1
False

//obj2
True
```

Comment: you're attempting to use your objects `obj1` & `obj2` before they are defined.

Comment: Still not clear what you want to try here.

Answer (score 0):

the objects do not exist at the time you try to use them. you need something like "isLoading" and when ur logic is done then u try to render